# How to guard parameter by interface?

Tags: typescript

There is an interface:

```
interface Data {
  A: number,
  B: number,
  C: number
}
```

And function:

```
let a = {
A:0,
B:0,
C:0
} as Data;

function set(value: any) {
      a[value]++;
}
```

How to guard parameter value, that use can not pass nothing besides keyes of interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html):

```
function set(value: keyof Data) {
  a[value]++;
}
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
function set(value: "A" | "B" | "C") {
  a[value]++;
}
```